# Associative Array within Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, get, associative-array

I am new to PHP and am trying to apply a named array within a named array. I have been able to apply each rope name (i.e. "Poly Soak") along with img, title, blurb, desc, etc. but am having a difficult time trying to apply `$specTable` into a table. I am also trying to apply `$applications` and `$benefits` with no luck.

I am using the using the GET command to generate each page. Pages populate as follows:

water-rescue-ropes.php?value=aqua-d 
water-rescue-ropes.php?value=poly-soak... etc

```
function strip_bad_chars( $input ) {
$output = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $input );
return $output; } 

if (isset($_GET['value'])) {
$waterRescueRope = strip_bad_chars( $_GET['value'] );
$rope = $waterRescueRopes[$waterRescueRope];}
```

Here is the ***edited*** array info:

```
$waterRescueRopes = array(
"poly-soak" => array(
    'img' => "3P",
    'title' => "Poly Soak&trade;",
    'blurb' => "Pelican’s 16 strand kernmantle construction is a...",
    'desc' => "Polypropylene Water Rescue Rope",
    'construction' => "16 Strand",
    'cover' => "Polypropylene",
    'core' => "Polypropylene",
        array(
            array(
                'sku'      => "3P-12Y",
                'diameter' => "3/8&quot;",
                'tensile' => 3000,
                'weight' => 3.4,
                ),
            array(
                'sku'      => "3P-14Y",
                'diameter' => "7/16&quot;",
                'tensile' => 3380,
                'weight' => 4.7,
                ),                  
        ),

        array("Water Rescue", "Canyoneering"),

        array("Lightweight", "Buoyant", "High Visibility"),         
),


"poly-soak-economy" => array(
    'img' => "FQK",
    'title' => "Poly Soak&trade; Economy",
    'blurb' => "All the great benefits and features of our Poly Soak rope but at a lower cost.",
    'desc' => "Polypropylene Economy Water Rescue Rope",
    'construction' => "16 Strand",
    'cover' => "Polypropylene",
    'core' => "Polypropylene",
        array(
            array(
                'sku'      => "FQK-502",
                'diameter' => "1/8&quot;",
                'tensile' => 2000,
                'weight' => 1.5,
                ),
        ),

        array("Water Rescue"),

        array("Economical", "Lightweight", "Buoyant"),      
),

"poly-soak-2" => array(
    'img' => "3PN",
    'title' => "Poly Soak&trade;",
    'blurb' => "This UL certified polypropylene rope is approved for...",
    'desc' => "NFPA&reg; Water Rescue Rope",
    'construction' => "24 Strand",
    'cover' => "Polypropylene",
    'core' => "Polypropylene",
        array(
            array(
                'sku'      => "3PN-12Y",
                'diameter' => "3/8&quot;",
                'tensile' => 4200,
                'weight' => 3.05,
                ),
        ),

        array("Water Rescue", "Canyoneering", "Mooring"),

        array("Bright Colors for Greater Visibility", "Supple for Compact Storage", "Certified to the Highest Standard", "Buoyant"),        
),

"aqua-d" => array(
    'img' => "3q",
    'title' => "Aqua-D&trade;",
    'blurb' => "This water rescue rope has a blended Dyneema® and polypropylene core. With a multifilament polypropylene cover, this rope floats and has near zero water retention. It is extremely strong, light 'weight', and has a no-stretch braid that meets the needs of coastal and river rescue professionals worldwide.",
    'desc' => "Dyneema® Polypropylene Water Rescue Rope",
    'construction' => "16 Strand",
    'cover' => "Polypropylene",
    'core' => "Dyneema®",
        array(
            array(
                'sku'      => "3Q-08Y",
                'diameter' => "1/4&quot;",
                'tensile' => "3200",
                'weight' => "1.7",
                ),
            array(
                'sku'      => "3Q-10Y",
                'diameter' => "5/16&quot;",
                'tensile' => "3400",
                'weight' => "2.3",
                ),
            array(
                'sku'      => "3Q-12Y",
                'diameter' => "3/8&quot;",
                'tensile' => "4950",
                'weight' => "3.4",
                ),
        ),

        array("Minimal Water Retention", "Strong &amp; Lightweight", "Buoyant"),

        array("Water Rescue"),      
), );
```

Additional included functions:

```
 function get_specs($array = false)
    {
        if (!is_array($array))
            return array();
        elseif(empty($array))
            return array();

        foreach($array as $polytype => $polydata) {
                $new[$polytype]['specs']        =   (!empty($polydata[0]))? $polydata[0]:array();
                $new[$polytype]['applications'] =   (!empty($polydata[1]))? $polydata[1]:array();
                $new[$polytype]['benefits']     =   (!empty($polydata[2]))? $polydata[2]:array();
            }

        return $new;
    }
```

Here is the ***edited*** specTable:

```
<?php function display_specs($spec = array(),$name = false)
    {
        if(!empty($spec[$name]['specs'])) {
                ob_start();
                foreach($spec[$name]['specs'] as $specs) {
                ?> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><?php echo $specs['sku']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $specs['diameter']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $specs['tensile']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $specs['weight']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }

                $data   =   ob_get_contents();

            }
    } ?>

// Isolates the specs from the main array
$specs  =   get_specs($waterRescueRopes);

// Alternately, you can loop through the main array and get all 
<?php foreach($specs as $polytype => $spec) {
    echo display_specs($specs,$_GET['value']);
}
 ?>
```

***Edited*** Applications (Benefits is in similar list):

```
<?php function display_applications($spec = array(),$name = false)
    {
        if(!empty($spec[$name]['applications'])) {
                ob_start();
                foreach($spec[$name]['applications'] as $apps) {
                ?> 
                <li><?php echo $apps; ?></li>
                <?php
                    }

                $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                return $data;
            } 
    }
?>
 <tr valign='top'>
     <td class="td-item-cell"><article>
         <div class="rel_product_wrapper">
             <h3>Applications</h3>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <?php
                     foreach($specs as $polytype => $spec) {
                     echo display_applications($specs,$_GET['value']);
                     }
                     ?>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </article></td>
 </tr>
```

I currently have them populating what I need but multiple times ( four times for the four types of rope, I am assuming).

Thank you for your time! I appreciate it! :)

Comment: Do you not get some kind of errors for those keys? `$spec[sku]` -> `$spec['sku']` *(should have quotes)* Do you have errors on?

Comment: Also, all your keys in your original array should have quotes: `array( 'img' => "3P",...etc...`

Comment: Keys need to be quoted if they are a string. `array('something'=>1);` no quote needed: `array(234234=>1);`

Comment: I didn't receive any error and errors are on (I'm using Dreamweaver). I've added single quotation marks where you emphasized (i.e. 'img', $spec ['sku'], etc), however, the $spec table still isn't populating  (or applications/benefits).

Comment: You won't receive any errors on Dreamweaver because if they are not quoted, that means they are assumed to be `CONSTANTS` which don't need to be quoted, but constants need to be defined differently. Put `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your page inside a `<?php` tag. That will show you any errors going on

Comment: Also, can you show your whole `$waterRescueRopes` array? Or is it too big?

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated the post. Thanks for everything. I really appreciate you.

Comment: Am I supposed to change anything on the HTML side? I am getting an error which reads "Notice: Undefined index: sku in water-rescue-ropes.php on line 116" and on 186. When I turn the error reporting off, the table is blank and under applications and benefits they both say "array".

Comment: Let me take a look! I think you may have to change how you are doing your main array. Give me a second to test it.

Comment: Also, how is your main array generated? From a database?

Comment: As of right now, I am just on localhost. Each array will be based off of the type of rope it is (i.e. water rescue, fire rescue).

Comment: Ok solution #2. You will just have to modify your foreach a bit for your spec table and other ones.

Comment: The proper PHP terminology for these is Associative Arrays. Other languages call them Dictionaries or HashMaps.

Comment: I have added an explanation of why your array does not work and why you only get the last set of variables. See my answer.

Comment: I literally have 0% idea how I am supposed to convert the tables, applications and benefits. :( Don't really even know where to add the function as when I look at the page its just jumbled at either the top or bottom of the page. I've posted a photo of what I'm getting.

Comment: Hey! Don't fret! I will make my explanation clearer with everything you have submitted so far. Where is the photo? I don't see any photo.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EgNR9.jpg

Comment: Okay, see my revision. Try the spec table first, see my notations.

Comment: I updated it with an application_display function so you can see how that works.

Comment: Every single table has the poly-soak data. I need for it to know, which table to read without having to enter "poly-soak" in echo display_specs($specs,"poly-soak");

Comment: Otherwise, I am going to have to make an individual page for each rope. Also, applications are not working.

Comment: The loop in my example does each product in the array (`foreach($specs as $polytype => $spec)`). Based on your array, I have the applications working. What does the applications say for an error or is it just blank?

Comment: Also the apps may not appear to work because I also used `<tr><td></td></tr>` which may not display on the page if not in a table (Yours look like they are in an `<li>` tag?).

Comment: I'm getting an error only for applications. But the table either only inputs "poly-soak" into each type of rope page or it loops and shows all the rope skus on one page. Here is a photo:http://i.stack.imgur.com/QvZRP.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the variables in your array, then create a function to extract just those aspects you need separately. The reason what you are doing does not work is because each time you write `$specTable` on each array, you re-assign/overwrite the previously-assigned `$specTable` to the current array until finally it is assigned the last array in the main array. That is why only one shows up. You need to save out those aspects to new arrays:

**FUNCTIONS:** Place functions at the top of the page OR in a different file that you include on this page for use. It is better to include using something like `include("function.specs.php")` because then you can reuse the functions on different pages if you want.

```
    function get_specs($array = false)
        {
            if (!is_array($array))
                return array();
            elseif(empty($array))
                return array();

            foreach($array as $polytype => $polydata) {
                    $new[$polytype]['specs']        =   (!empty($polydata[0]))? $polydata[0]:array();
                    $new[$polytype]['applications'] =   (!empty($polydata[1]))? $polydata[1]:array();
                    $new[$polytype]['benefits']     =   (!empty($polydata[2]))? $polydata[2]:array();
                }

            return $new;
        }

    function display_specs($spec = array(),$name = false)
        {
            if(!empty($spec[$name]['specs'])) {
                    ob_start();
                    foreach($spec[$name]['specs'] as $specs) {
                    ?> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $specs['sku']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $specs['diameter']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $specs['tensile']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $specs['weight']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }

                    $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                    return $data;
                }
        }

    // For sake of ease, you can do an application one by itself,
    // Normally, you could just do one class/method that handles all the
    // the different arrays
    function display_applications($spec = array(),$name = false)
        {
            if(!empty($spec[$name]['applications'])) {
                    ob_start();
                    foreach($spec[$name]['applications'] as $apps) {
                    ?> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $apps; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }

                    $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                    return $data;
                }
        }
```

**Using the functions on your page:**

```
    // Isolates the specs from the main array
    $specs  =   get_specs($waterRescueRopes);
    // To select one product out of the bunch, just use the name from the array.
    // Note, you need the $specs array as the first argument
    echo display_specs($specs,"poly-soak");
    echo display_applications($specs,"poly-soak");
    // Alternately, you can loop through the main array and get all: ?>
<table>
<?php
foreach($specs as $polytype => $spec) {
        echo display_specs($specs,$polytype);
        echo display_applications($specs,$polytype);
    }
?>
</table>
```

**Applications Part:** Because the function already does the loop for you, you just need to echo it:

```
<tr valign='top'>
     <td class="td-item-cell"><article>
         <div class="rel_product_wrapper">
             <h3>Applications</h3>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <?php echo display_applications($specs,$_GET['value']); ?>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </article></td>
 </tr>
```

**The RAW print_r($specs) gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [poly-soak] => Array
        (
            [specs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 3P-12Y
                            [diameter] => 3/8&quot;
                            [tensile] => 3000
                            [weight] => 3.4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 3P-14Y
                            [diameter] => 7/16&quot;
                            [tensile] => 3380
                            [weight] => 4.7
                        )

                )

            [applications] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Water Rescue
                    [1] => Canyoneering
                )

            [benefits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lightweight
                    [1] => Buoyant
                    [2] => High Visibility
                )

        )

    [poly-soak-economy] => Array
        (
            [specs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => FQK-502
                            [diameter] => 1/8&quot;
                            [tensile] => 2000
                            [weight] => 1.5
                        )

                )

            [applications] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Water Rescue
                )

            [benefits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Economical
                    [1] => Lightweight
                    [2] => Buoyant
                )

        )

    [poly-soak-2] => Array
        (
            [specs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 3PN-12Y
                            [diameter] => 3/8&quot;
                            [tensile] => 4200
                            [weight] => 3.05
                        )

                )

            [applications] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Water Rescue
                    [1] => Canyoneering
                    [2] => Mooring
                )

            [benefits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bright Colors for Greater Visibility
                    [1] => Supple for Compact Storage
                    [2] => Certified to the Highest Standard
                    [3] => Buoyant
                )

        )

    [aqua-d] => Array
        (
            [specs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 3Q-08Y
                            [diameter] => 1/4&quot;
                            [tensile] => 3200
                            [weight] => 1.7
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 3Q-10Y
                            [diameter] => 5/16&quot;
                            [tensile] => 3400
                            [weight] => 2.3
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 3Q-12Y
                            [diameter] => 3/8&quot;
                            [tensile] => 4950
                            [weight] => 3.4
                        )

                )

            [applications] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Minimal Water Retention
                    [1] => Strong &amp; Lightweight
                    [2] => Buoyant
                )

            [benefits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Water Rescue
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: **Ok so first:** The `display_applications` error is saying you are not including that function on the page. See my **functions** code snippit for that function (bottom of that snippit).

Comment: Secondly, how do you select each product because you have supplied a full range of products in an array, but you need to isolate one of them. When you click a product to view, how does your website know which product to display?

Comment: Ok so you use a `$_GET`, then you should be able to isolate using `$_GET['value']` like `echo display_specs($specs,$_GET['value']);` and `echo display_applications($specs,$_GET['value']);`

Comment: Ok, so that helped a lot and is getting me to where I need to be! :) The only thing now is that it is looping all the information four times each for both the table and the applications.

Comment: Edit your post to show the total applications code as you have it now.

Comment: Ok, see my revision in the **Applications Part:** for those explanations.

Comment: YAY! Using <?php echo display_name($specs,$_GET['value']); ?> on all three of the arrays worked! I am so happy right now. Thank you so much. You are the best. :D